# Scrapy stops crawling at seemingly random point

Tags: python, scrapy, limit

**Set-up**

I'm scraping London housing ads from [this site](https://www.gumtree.com/property-to-rent/london).

One can search for housing ads on 3 different area sizes: the entirety of London, in a specific district (e.g. Central London) or in a specific sub district (e.g. Aldgate).

The site only allows you to check 50 pages of each 30 ads per area, regardless the size of the area. I.e. if I select X, I can view 1500 ads in X, whether X is Central London or Aldgate.

At the moment of writing this question there are over 37.000 ads on the site.

Since I want to scrape as many ads as possible, this limitation implies I need to scrape ads on sub district level.

To do so, I have written the following spider,

```
# xpath to area/sub area links
area_links = ('''//*[@id="fullListings"]/div[1]/div/div/nav/aside/'''
          '''section[1]/div/ul/li/a/@href''')

class ApartmentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apartments2'
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.gumtree.com/property-to-rent/london"
        ]

    # obtain links to london areas
    def parse(self, response):                
            for url in response.xpath(area_links).extract():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),
                         callback=self.parse_sub_area)    

    # obtain links to london sub areas
    def parse_sub_area(self, response):                
            for url in response.xpath(area_links).extract():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),
                         callback=self.parse_ad_overview)    

    # obtain ads per sub area page
    def parse_ad_overview(self, response):                
            for ads in response.xpath('//*[@id="srp-results"]/div[1]/div/div[2]',
                                      ).css('ul').css('li').css('a',
                                           ).xpath('@href').extract():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(ads),
                         callback=self.parse_ad)

                next_page = response.css(
            '#srp-results > div.grid-row > div > ul > li.pagination-next > a',
                                        ).xpath('@href').extract_first()
                if next_page is not None:
                    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse) 

    # obtain info per ad
    def parse_ad(self, response):

    # here follows code to extract of data per ad
```

which works fine.

That is, it obtains the links to the,

1. areas from the initial page
2. sub areas from the respective area page, per area
3. housing ads per sub area page, iterating over all pages per sub area

to finally scrape the data from each individual ad.

---

**Problem**

The code stops scraping seemingly at random, and I do not know why.

I suspect it has hit a limit as it is told to scrape many links and items, but am unsure if I'm right.

When it stops, it states,

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1295950,
 'downloader/request_count': 972,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 972,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 61697740,
 'downloader/response_count': 972,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 972,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1806,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 4, 17, 13, 35, 53156),
 'item_scraped_count': 865,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1839,
 'log_count/ERROR': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 972,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 971,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 971,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 971,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 971,
 'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 5,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 4, 17, 9, 56, 132388)}
```

I'm not sure if one can read from this whether I've hit a limit or something, but if anyone does know, please let me know if I did and how to prevent the code from stopping.

Comment: You are only getting status 200 responses. If something goes really wrong or you are getting blocked, you would get service unavailable responses (503) or similar. Do you think the code stops prematurely, because the item count varies across different runs?

Comment: Hi Andras, I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean with 'the item count varies across different runs'.

Comment: Why do you think your code stops scraping prematurely?

Comment: I think that it has to do too much at the same time. There are over 60 sub areas, with each 50 pages and 30 ads per page. Perhaps the code is iterating over too many at once.

Comment: You have to track down where the code is quitting. Are all the ads you have successfully scraped from the same area for example? You could start with scraping only one area and seeing if you can get all the ads. If that works, try scraping the first two areas and so on. If it doesn't work, track down where the code breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the complete or at least partial log of crawling process is going to help you troubleshooting,  but I'm going to take a risk and post this answer because I see one thing; I'm assuming is the issue

```
def parse_ad_overview(self, response):                
            for ads in response.xpath('//*[@id="srp-results"]/div[1]/div/div[2]',
                                      ).css('ul').css('li').css('a',
                                           ).xpath('@href').extract():
                yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(ads),
                         callback=self.parse_ad)

                next_page = response.css(
            '#srp-results > div.grid-row > div > ul > li.pagination-next > a',
                                        ).xpath('@href').extract_first()
                if next_page is not None:
                    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I'm pretty sure I know what's going on,  ran into similar issues in the past and looking at your script when you are running your next page from the last function the Callback sends it back to parse... of which I assume that the link to next page is on thatinstances http responce... so just change the callback to parse_ad_overview ...